# FullCalendar hacer que acepte formato de hora AM PM con moment.js

Tags: fullcalendar

**Aquí esta mi código**

```
dayRender:function(diaSeleccionado,dbClick)
{
    dbClick.bind('dblclick',function(){
        $('#ModalAdd #event_FechaInicio').val(moment(diaSeleccionado).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(diaSeleccionado).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        $('#ModalAdd #event_InicioHora').val(moment(diaSeleccionado).format('hh:mm'));
        $('#ModalAdd #event_FinHora').val(moment(diaSeleccionado).format('hh:mm'));
        $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
    })
},
```

Comment: Podrías ser mas especifico sobre el problema que tienes?

Comment: El problema es que cuando guardo en la BD un evento de la sieguiente forma: Hora_Inicio : 27/12/2017 5:15 PM........... FullCalendar me lo pone un dia antes y con una hora que ni se de donde sale por ejemplo: 26/12/2017 1:00 sin el PM o AM

Comment: Tambien le puse hora_Final y sigue igual, me pone un dia antes del que se eligio en el calendario y una hora diferente tambien :(

Comment: antes de hacer el registro de la bd haz consultado la información que envía?

Comment: En la BD se guarda asi: 27/12/2017 5:15 PM y cuando hago la consulta para mostrarlo en el fullCalendar me sale un dia antes y una hora rara, asi: 26/12/2017 1:00

Comment: a ok, tu problema esta entonces es cuando pasas de la BD al componente, pensaba que era al contrario.

Comment: El problema esta en FullCalendar, porque antes cuando yo no trabajaba con BD, pongo una fecha con su hora y el final tambien y me ponia un dia antes

Comment: si a eso me referia, disculpa no fui claro, veo, que versión estas usando de full calendar?

Comment: FullCalendar 3.7.0

Comment: podrías actualizar tu pregunta y poner una breve muestra del calendario para ver como lo estas haciendo.

Comment: No hay otra forma que me pueda comunicar contigo para poder enviarte capturas, etc???

Comment: andres@wookplay.com